# auto-loading ruler-mode while in text-mode

Tags: text-editing

I have configured evolution to use Emacs for me to edit my replies to emails I receive.  However, I need to limit my line length to around 72 characters to avoid the odd-ball line wrapping by the mailer (MicroSoft EWS).

I currently have the following line in my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (quote("/tmp/evo*\\'" . text-mode))
```

So that the files are put in `text-mode`.  However, I would also like to invoke `ruler-mode` automatically instead of having to do it manually.

But I cannot seem to figure this one out.  Is there a text hook I can add a custom function on to deal with this?

(GNU Emacs 24.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 and GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on private red-hat like distro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hook for text-mode, and it's called `text-mode-hook`. You can use it like so:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'ruler-mode)
```

You might also be interested in auto-fill-mode, which you can set to hard-wrap your lines at 72 automatically. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html#Auto-Fill) for details. The short version is you set the fill column to 72, turn on `auto-fill-mode`, and then whenever you add text beyond column 72 Emacs will insert a new line at the appropriate place for you. You can also refill a paragraph if the line lengths got disrupted when you made changes somewhere in the middle with `M-q`.

Comment: Okay, I really only need to invoke this when the buffer is /tmp/evo* name, so I see a new private defun in my future.  Thanks this is helpful.